# How can I create a Apple Watch complication that has multi colors?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

My objective is to create an Apple Watch complication that has multiple colors. Specifically, I want the multi-colored template image that I submit to stay multi-colored instead of defaulting to white. This is on a multi-colored watch face, I know the color will be overridden if the user selects a color tint for their watch face.

What code would I put into which files to keep my complication template multi-colored?

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` has a parameter to define how it is rendered on screen when placed inside of an `UIImageView`.

If you're loading this image in your code you'll need to set `UIImage.RenderingMode` to `.alwaysOriginal` in order to have the system display its colors when there's no tint override. However, if you're simply loading from an Xcode Asset Catalog, just select the asset and then change the rendering mode from the menu in the Inspector.

[image: Render As... dialog in XCAsset Catalog]

Select the Inspector, then select *Original Image* from the *Render As* dropdown.

See the [developer documentation on rendering mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode).

Comment: I'm loading from an Xcode Asset Catalog. How do you select the asset and change the rending mode from the menu in the Inspector? That is what I'm stuck on.

Comment: @RyanMartinson see my edit above with the screenshot ^. Make sure you've selected all relevant asset variations and then select "Original Image" in the "Render As" dropdown from the Inspector.